# Reading any xml from physical location

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have to read any xml file from physical location. 
I was doing like below way, But, it is saying file now found.

Example, I can have any file (a.xml, b.xml, c.xml,..... z.xml)
So I want to use a common code to read xml.

Any help?
Thank You

Comment: Which file content do you want if there are several files matching *.xml? All of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for `Load()` should be a single file. You could iterate over an array of files to open the documents.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string folder = "C:\\";

        // Loop trough all
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.xml"))
        {
            var document = XDocument.Load(file);
        }

        // When it should explicitly be one
        var singleFile = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xml").SingleOrDefault();
        if (singleFile == null) throw new Exception("File missing or multiple files found");
        var document = XDocument.Load(singleFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this post with `vb.net` here is a vb answer.

```vb
Dim fileList as new List(of FileInfo)
dim basepath as string = "drive:\path\to\base\folder"

fileList = new IO.DirectoryInfo(basepath).GetFiles("*.xml")

For each fle in fileList
    Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load(fle.FullName)
    objIntegrationInfo.xmlstring += xDoc.ToString()
Next
```